# Как убрать ссылки без потери css

Tags: html, css

Есть такое меню

```css
.navbar ul li a {
  background-color: #949494;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="zernosushilnoe-oborudovanie/ochistka-zerna/">Зерноочистительные машины</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Я хочу убрать ссылки `<a>` из тегов `<li>` без потери стилей (!!!Сами стили менять нельзя), могу лия оставить такой вид:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Зерноочистительные машины</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Вроде бы работает как надо?

Answer (score 1):

Валидатор w3 будет ругаться если нет коректного href у ссылки.

"Я хочу убрать ссылки `<a>` из тегов `<li>` без потери стилей"

Если ити на еще большие костыли, то можно поставить событие click c return false. Тогда не произойдет переход по ссылке

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar ul li span {
  background-color: #949494;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Зерноочистительные машины</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS: Убирать ссылки из меню - так себе идея.